# ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack - Glove

Tags: glove

I downloaded the Glove model 
https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/

and I train the Glove model use my own corpus, I didn't change anything else other than adding my own corpus. but it gives the following errors.

```
01/30/19 - 11:15.01AM, iter: 015, cost: 0.062701
$ python eval/python/evaluate.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eval/python/evaluate.py", line 110, in <module>
    main()
  File "eval/python/evaluate.py", line 33, in main
    evaluate_vectors(W_norm, vocab, ivocab)
  File "eval/python/evaluate.py", line 66, in evaluate_vectors
    ind1, ind2, ind3, ind4 = indices.T
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this error occurs, The corpus is generated correctly.